# what is the difference between two sentences*

Tags: meaning

1-)And soon they faced a crisis - **one that would decide the future of egypt.** 
 -2)And soon they faced a crisis - **one would decide the future of egypt.**

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence. One what? Are the two supposed to mean the same thing? **Maybe** in question 2 the crisis was the need to determine which of the two (people?) would be the one to decide the future of Egypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is grammatical, the second is not (or, more precisely, the second is grammatical only with a different and very unlikely meaning, taking *one* as an indefinite pronoun).

The relative pronoun ("which/who") or complementiser ("that") can be omitted from a relative clause *only  when it is not the subject of the relative clause*. Here, *that* (or the relative pronoun it replaces) *is* the subject of *would decide*, so it  cannot be omitted.